# How can I disable Cronjob Emails?

Tags: cron

I would like to disable my cronjob from sending me Emails.

My cronjob is executing a php file.

At the top of this file I wrote:

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php 
$ crontab -e
MAILTO=""
```

But this is not helping.

I also tried

```
#!/usr/bin/php
>/dev/null 2>&1.
```

Comment: comment the email sending line add comment symbol in start of line `#`

Comment: @EuphoriaGrogi Do you mean: `# MAILTO="" !/usr/bin/php`

Comment: I think you are confusing shell and php.

Comment: There is no code that you've posted that would send an email. Are you asking how to disable a specific cron job or are you asking how to comment a line in PHP?

Comment: @JeanDoux Yes, I do not know about shell. Only php. My php file is successfully executed. But I always get an automatic email from Cron Deamon. And I get it everytime the cronjob is executed. I just want to stop this, because it is every day.

Comment: Execute `crontab -e` from your commandline instead of doing it in a php script. It will open up in an editor of your choice and you can disable the mail from there on.

Comment: @Ciccio Thank you, but I have no idea how to open the command line of my host.

Comment: @EuphoriaGrogi Thank you, I wrote exactly `#MAILTO` at the top of the page, but still the automatic email is sent

Comment: @Jarla so you are not using shell for this? i think its not possible to manually open and edit the file

Comment: @EuphoriaGrogi No, my Host offers the option: activate cronjobs. and there I created a new cronjob, where I can set the path to my php file. This is working very well. Only the automatic email every day is annoying

Comment: Like @JeanDoux mentioned, you are confusing shell and PHP, you can do it in PHP, but not like this and only if the crontab you are trying to edit is owned by the same user that runs your webserver. Find out if your host has SSH access, connect and then execute `crontab -e`, or if your host uses parallels plesk or similar web interface, then add `&> /dev/null` to the end of the cron task in the webinterface (so behind the path of the file or command you are running).

Answer (score 2):

With putty connect to your server.

In the command line :

```
crontab -e
```

It will open you cron in editor. If it's vi the editor by default, Press "i" to insert mode. Then put on the first line

```
MAILTO=""
```

Press "Esc" to stop insert mode and ":x" to quit and save.

If you don't know how to connect to your server, you need to contact your sysAdmin.